# How to create a custom validator to check password and confirm password mismatch

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, customvalidator, angular11

I am working on Angular 11 project I want create a custom validator in reactive form. Here is the code

[image]
but it gives following errors

[image]

if I omit `.value` from `control.get('password').value` error is not shown but validator is not working.
How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

change `control.get('password').value` to `control.value['password']`
change `control.get('ConfirmPassword').value` to `control.value['confirmPassword']`

Answer (score 0):

You have problem because , object is possibly null. It's necessary create condition when is object password or confirm Password null return null.

So I am sharing my solution . This working for me.

[image]

Code is here

```
    this.userForm = new FormGroup(
  {
    name: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.email,
      Validators.minLength(4),
      Validators.maxLength(8),
    ]),
    email: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.email,
      Validators.pattern("^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$")
    ]),
    phone: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern("^((\\+91-?)|0)?[0-9]{10}$") // 10 characters
    ]),

    password: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(8),
    //  this.passwordStrengthValidator() // another Validator
    ]),
    password2: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    message: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  },

  //this.passwordMatch('password', 'password2') // working
  {
    validators: this.passwordMatch('password', 'password2') // working
  }
);

passwordMatch(password: string, confirmPassword: string): ValidatorFn {
return (formGroup: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
  const passwordControl = formGroup.get(password);
  const confirmPasswordControl = formGroup.get(confirmPassword);

  if (!passwordControl || !confirmPasswordControl) {
    return null;
  }

  if (
    confirmPasswordControl.errors &&
    !confirmPasswordControl.errors.mustMatch
  ) {
    return null;
  }

  if (passwordControl.value !== confirmPasswordControl.value) {
    confirmPasswordControl.setErrors({ mustMatch: true });
    return { mustMatch: true }
  } else {
    confirmPasswordControl.setErrors(null);
    return null;
  }
};
```

}